# Can't find a result with The Silver Searcher at a certain depth

Tags: ack, ag

I'm getting some odd behaviour with The Silver Searcher that I just discovered when looking for a line in my code base. In the root folder, I call

```
% ag branding_black_with_bundles
% ag --depth -1 branding_black_with_bundles
```

and get nothing. However, when I call the same with ack, I get the result

```
% ack branding_black_with_bundles
app/database/seeds/test_seeder/dumps/Swf.php
88: array("id"=>907,"title"=>"branding_black_with_bundles","original_filename"=>"original_filename","created_by_id"=>2,"created_at"=>"2013-09-14 18:16:12","updated_at"=>"2013-06-15 04:14:50"),
```

When I cd down one directory closer, I find it:

```
% cd app
% ag branding_black_with_bundles
database/seeds/test_seeder/dumps/Swf.php
88:    array("id"=>907,"title"=>"branding_black_with_bundles","original_filename"=>"original_filename","created_by_id"=>2,"created_at"=>"2013-09-14 18:16:12","updated_at"=>"2013-06-15 04:14:50"),
```

What is up? Is it a bug, or am I missing some kind of setting?

Comment: are any of those files ignored by version control? by default ag doesn't search them.  try `ag -U branding_black_with_bundles` to not use the default ignores.. (more info on the man page under Ignoring files). Guessing it is something like this,  since you probably have a .(git|hg)ignore in the root of your app, but once you go down into app directory it doesn't get processed

Comment: Good idea, but this file's not in gitignore, and `ag -U branding_black_with_bundles` also returns nothing :\

Comment: Aha! A previous dev had added it to .agignore, which -U doesn't ignore :) Thanks for setting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

My bad! It turns out the file with the result is specified under .agignore, and to avoid it I must use `ag -u branding_black_with_bundles`, and/or remove from the `.agignore` file.

As Doon said, it could well have been in `.gitignore` also, so if coming across this problem, best to check there also I think.